# erstmals wieder

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverb

I have read/heard the following sentence in https://learngerman.dw.com/de/20012024-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-68040812:

> US-Präsident Joe Biden hat erstmals wieder seit mehreren Wochen mit
> dem israelischen Regierungschef Benjamin Netanjahu telefoniert.

Usually, erstmals means "for the first time" and wieder means "again".

How is it possible to call someone on the phone for the first time again? The "again" part seems irrelevant to the context, even if the US president called the Israeli Prime Minister in the past. I tried translating it to English using DeepL Translator and indeed "wieder" was not included in the translation:

> US President Joe Biden has spoken to Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin
> Netanyahu on the phone for the first time in several weeks

Does "wieder" have a different meaning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the correct translation:

> US President Joe Biden spoke **again** to Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu on the phone for the first time in several weeks.

He spoke *again* because he had done it several times in the past. But he hadn't done it for several weeks, so this was *the first time* in several weeks.

Comment: Thanks, the German word order makes the meaning hard to understand. I don't think "again" would be usually used in the English sentence because it's clear from "the first time in several weeks" that the two presidents have already talked in the past.

Comment: @Alan Evangelista - I'm pretty sure German word order makes perfect sense to native German speakers. That's said, I'm not entirely convinced that the phrasing is optimal in this case. Perhaps "US-Präsident Joe Biden hat erstmals seit mehreren Wochen wieder mit dem israelischen Regierungschef Benjamin Netanjahu telefoniert." would be an improvement.